# updating data in a CSV file

Tags: c, linux, csv

hi every one i want to read and write data from a CSV file using c program. but my problem is that at run time my data is increasing in both row wise and column wise. that means it is continuously updating in both direction.

is there any way through which i can find the next colum or row for eg (row 4 ,col 3) and place my data into it

one thing more it is not necessary that that all rows have same number of column filled 
any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Do you mean CSV rather than CVS?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you keep the data in memory and just write it out to an csv file if you are ready? Or another option, just us a line feed as indicator that a new data element will come? Or maybe it would be an option to think about some kind of structure you can use and modify and just in the end you write out the .csv file?
Or well if the structure is that inhomogenous why stick to csv?

Because my answer is somewhat  burried in the comments. The current suggestion with all the commens is that he needs a way to read in something from a csv file. Than that he has to keep track of the things he wants to track (IP connections) and that the file can be regenerated all 30 or so seconds.

Comment: actually i want to store data which is updating in both direction text file will creat a mess so i thought cvs woulf be fine. also i need that datato make a graph . can u suggest me any other way that how to store that data

Comment: I'm sorry but you do not have posted your "goal" really. There are other ways of storing away things. You can e.g use some Database be it in a structured ways like (relational databases) you can use things like Databased which you access via keys. E.g Berkeley DB or any other NoSQL database. You can write out JSON stuff to disk, you can use XML. In you case maybre JSON would be an option?

Comment: +1 for "why stick to CSV". The proper way to solve this is to use in-memory data structures and translate those from and to CSV, not to edit CSV files in-place.

Comment: but the data is increasing in both direction how to cator that? is there away to keep a pointer like can i access something like that in cvs file [row ,col]. plz help thanks so much

Comment: one thing more cant use data base because my program need alot of cvs file all will be created at run time and will be updated conrinously ...thanks

Comment: This does not make sense. Even if the strucure will grow you do not have to write out csv files always. You can use a List, expandable arrays, dictionaries, hash tables etc. But you should know what data you expect. How else should one decide which way to go?

Comment: i am not getting u sir. kindly explaing your point.also i have to use that data add specific columns and make graphs is it possible through arrays thanks

Comment: I can't get more concrete because you do not provide what you really want to achieve and if you do not know what I mean with lists, arrays etc how could anything I wrote be of any help?

Comment: sir lets i am sorry if i hurt u let me explain in detail

Comment: i have to maintain an information of data flown between pair of two ip address i will update my database after every 30 sec. also i have to maintain an information that how many session are active between two pair of ip address (same ips but different ports) to keep the data and number of session i need an csv file in which i will keep the data flow record in column and session info in row  thank

Comment: Then I can not understand why you need it all in the csv file. It will be fine if you regenerate a csv file very 30 seconds. But the programm could keep the informations in a list of lists e.g a list of ip addresses and a list of used Ports. There's not need to extend or modify the csv file. Just write out your data every 30 seconds.

Comment: i have to maintain all the data from start till end with an interval of 30 sec.any way i woont waste your time thank u freidrich sir for your help and concern :)

Comment: So you need a way to read in the csv file, handle the incoming things and then you write a csv file. So the way to go is "clear". Built a nice in-memory datastructure from the csv file, during runtime update this data and if you are done write it down into a csv file.

Comment: I would use a data structure with three fields:

row, col, value

You can just update the line that is for the cell you want to change or add a line for a new cell.  Then you can create the csv style grid by just pivoting the data on the col field - that way it doesn't matter what order the new cells are created.